# What happens to non-Hindus in the afterlife?

Tags: karma, other-religions

How is the soul of a non-Hindu processed in the afterlife?  Is it as decribed in Hindu scripture, or is it as described in the scriptures of the religion that they belonged to?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Do you mean people following other religions take rebirth? Do you also mean a Hindu can take rebirth in other faith (say islam)?

Comment: I don't think soul's have any religion. It's all man made.

Comment: I made correction in question. I added more specification. please answer.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking whether people of other religions go to the Hindu afterlife or to the afterlife of the religion they belonged to?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan : no, all the procedure after death happened as per hinduism books or same as human’s own religion books?

Comment: OK, let me edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @SamSol I edited your question, does it reflect your intent?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan : Perfect my friend. thanks a lot. 

Comment: The same thing that happens to Hindus.

Answer (score 2):

Hardly that they are processed as described in the scriptures of the religion that they belong to.
Teachings of any tradition, be it within Hinduism or outside of it, is not true if it is not in conformity with Hindu dharma teachings.
This is stated in the Manu-smriti, chapter 12:
http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu12.htm

> 94. The Veda is the eternal eye of the manes, gods, and men; the Veda-ordinance (is) both beyond the sphere of (human) power, and
>       beyond the sphere of (human) comprehension; that is a certain fact.
> 95. All those traditions (smriti) and those despicable systems of philosophy, which are not based on the Veda, produce no reward after
>       death; for they are declared to be founded on Darkness.
> 96. All those (doctrines), differing from the (Veda), which spring up and (soon) perish, are worthless and false, because they are of modern
>       date.